# Class change for rows on mouse over works for unchanged rows, but doesn't work sorted rows for DataTable

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I am having a following script which works like this:

When i am hovering on rows, then the current hovered row gets a class attached to it called .sorting_1....

The thing works well..

But say, when i click on a cloumn header to sort the rows w.r.t that column, then when i hover on the rows, the rows dont get the class .sorting_1 attached to it

Here's my piece of code.

```
$("#campaigns_list tr").not(":first").hover(
                          function () {
                            $(this).find("td").addClass("sorting_1");
                          }, 
                          function () {
                            $(this).find("td").removeClass("sorting_1");
                          }
                        );
```

Thin is, how can i sort this issue out?

Answer (score 1):

Try [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#campaigns_list tr:not(":first")', function () {
   $(this).find("td").addClass("sorting_1");
}).on('mouseleave', '#campaigns_list tr:not(":first")', function() {
   $(this).find("td").removeClass("sorting_1");
});
```